# Weird memory issue in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I have encountered a pretty weird problem in C.

This is my function:

```
void array_insert_range(void* dest[], const void* source[], unsigned int index, size_t length_dest, const size_t length_source)
{
    dest = (void**)realloc(dest, (length_dest+length_source) * sizeof(void*));
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < length_source; j++)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = length_dest+length_source-1; i >= index; i--)
        {
            dest[i+1] = dest[i];
        }
    }
    for(unsigned int i = index; i<index+length_source; i++)
    {
       dest[i] = source[i-index];
    }
}
```

And here are some testcases I wrote for it:

```
int* arr = array_create(7, sizeof(int));
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
arr[4] = 5;
arr[5] = 6;
arr[6] = 7;
int* arr2 = array_create(4, sizeof(int));
arr2[0] = 1;
arr2[1] = 2;
arr2[2] = 3;
arr2[3] = 4;
array_insert_range(arr, arr2, 3, 7, 4);
```

This should result in *arr* being an array with the elements *{1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7}*.

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 with GCC 4.8.1 and GDB 7.6.1. When I run my project with the debugger, the code works just fine. However, if I just compile and run normally, the array contains some weird values, for example *{9472560,7988328,3,4,5,6,7,-1,888981658,134220576,9443152}*.

I tried printing the value at different points in the program, and it seems like the array *dest* is fine at the end of the *array_insert_range* method, the odd values only appear in the testcase method.

I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: `dest[i+1]` will break the array on the first iteration of the nested loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `array_insert_range` takes pointers of pointer on void as first and second arguments: in argument declaration, `void* dest[]` is equivalent to `void** dest`. When you call this function in your testcase, your compiler must complain about that.

So the correct thing to do is to call `array_insert_range` with the address of `arr1`:

```
array_insert_range(&arr1, arr2, 3, 7, 4);
```

Also, you need to change the declaration of this function in order to get the address of `arr1`:

```
void array_insert_range(void** dest[], const void* source[], unsigned int index, size_t length_dest, const size_t length_source);
```

Then, in the code of the function, use `*dest` instead of `dest`.

Comment: That partially solved the problem. I also had to add another asterisk to the function declaration (void*** dest instead of void** dest) and dereference the pointer in the call to realloc(). Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I forgot to note that. It may works in debug mode if the reallocation does not change the address of `dest`.